# file access after unshare mount namespace

Tags: linux, mount, unshare

I`ll be glad to get an explanation how unshar mount namespace works
for the following code:

```
unshare (mount_ns)
int pid = fork()
if (pid ==0)
{
   makedir("myDir");
   mount("path", "myDir", 0);
   int fd = open("myDir/myFile.txt", O_CREATE|O_RDWR);
   
   wrte(fd, "123\n",4);
   close(fd);
}
sleep(100000);
if(pid == 0)
{
   if (open("myDir/myFile.txt", O_RDONLY) < 0)
      printf ("son proc failed to read file\n");
   else
      printf ("son proc ok to read file\n");
}
else
{
    if (open("myDir/myFile.txt", O_RDONLY) < 0)
      printf ("parent proc failed to read file\n");
   else
      printf ("parent proc failed to read file\n");
}
```

I expected to see `son proc ok to read file`, `parent proc failed to read file`
but both success. How can it be after unshare?

Answer (score 0):

I assume its a C code. There seems to be multiple mistakes in the code that you provided.

**First of all**, you would not realize that parent success to read the file because:

```
if (open("myDir/myFile.txt", O_RDONLY) < 0)
  printf ("parent proc failed to read file\n");
else
  printf ("parent proc failed to read file\n");
```

should be

```
if (open("myDir/myFile.txt", O_RDONLY) < 0)
  printf ("parent proc failed to read file\n");
else
  printf ("parent proc ok to read file\n");
```

**Moreover**, maybe the following:

```
int fd = open("myDir/myFile.txt", O_CREATE|O_RDWR);
wrte(fd, "123\n",4);
```

should be:

```
int fd = open("myDir/myFile.txt", O_CREAT|O_RDWR);
write(fd, "123\n",4);
```

**Additionnally:**

If you unshare your mount namespace BEFORE the fork, you will expect both parent and child belonging to the same mount namespace.

Maybe you should move the 'unshare (mount_ns)' somewhere else like this:

```
int pid = fork()
if (pid ==0) {
  unshare (mount_ns)
  makedir("myDir");
  ...
```

Best regards.